# How to load a new view on button click in iPhone view based application without using UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am a newbie in iPhone development, and have searched alot on internet. I am using a view based application template, basically I want to load a new view on button click, lets say when a user clicks on a button e.g. when the user click on login it should load a new view? Any help on this would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new view controller, then add its view to the existing view:

```
MyViewController * vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myviewcontroller"...
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```